# $N$ a normal subgroup of $G$ with $|G|$ odd and $|N|=5$ satisfies $N \subset Z(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Exercise

Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Suppose that $|N|=5$ and that $|G|$ is odd. Show that $N \subset Z(G)$.

I am sorry for not writing any work of mine but I really don't know where to start. I would appreciate any hints that could help me to have an idea of what to do.

Comment: This is false, let $G=D_5$, the Dihedral group of order $10$. Then if the unique subgroup of order $5$ were in the center it would commute with everything and the group would be abelian.

Comment: That's not correct. One can take, for example, $G=D_{5}$.

Comment: Sorry guys, thanks for the remark. English is not my native language and I sometimes mistake even for odd. I've edited the post, I've meant odd, not even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general if $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then there is an injective homomorphism $G/C_G(N) \hookrightarrow \text{Aut}(N)$ (here $C_G(N)=\{g\in G : gn=ng \text{ for all } n \in N\}$, the centralizer of $N$ in $G$). This can be seen by the conjugation action of $G$ on $N$. Since in this case $N\cong C_5$, $\text{Aut}(N)\cong C_4$ and $|G|$ is odd, it follows that $G=C_G(N)$, that is $N \subseteq Z(G)$.
The statement can be generalized to $|N|$ being a *Fermat prime number* (of the form $2^{2^{n}}+1$).

Answer (score 0):

$G$ acts on $N$ by conjugation, hence permuting the non-identity elements of $N$. That action defines a homomorphism
$$\rho:G\to S_4.$$
Since $G$ is has odd order, $\rho$ sends $G$ to one of the cyclic subgroups $C_3$ in $S_4$. It follows that $G$ fixes a non-identity element of $N$. Since any non-identity element of $N$ is a generator, $G$ fixes all elements of $N$.

Comment: I think I could follow all your answer except for one thing: you say that since $G$ has odd order then $\rho$ sends $G$ to one of the cyclic $C_3$ subgroups. I suppose this is deduced from the fact that the order of the image divides the order of $G$, maybe this is too obvious but why can't the order of the image be $1$? I see that this would mean that $G$ is abelian.

Comment: That doesn't mean $G$ is abelian, it only means that the image of $G$ is. And I was actually trying to show that the order of the image is $1$.

Comment: Why does the action of $\;G\;$ on $\;N\;$ induces a homomorphism to $\;S_4\;$ *precisely*?

Comment: @Timbuc: There are $4$ non-identity elements of $N$.